# How to make Nvidia Surround work?

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, nvidia-graphics-card, dvi, displayport

So, I had never had a nvidia graphics card before, I recently got the GTX 1070 G1 Gaming and I intend to have 3 monitors hooked up to it, not just for gaming, but for general use too. This graphics card has 3 dp ports, 1 hdmi and 1 dvi, and im really confused about what kind of monitors i need to buy, i read  that i need to use at least one display port, my idea was to just buy 3 monitors that have displayport, but then, i read that its not as simple as getting 3 displayport cables and hooking them up, so whats the ideal way to setup surround ?

3 displayports ?

one of each (dp/hdmi/dvi)?

do i need monitors that have displayport, or can i get ones that have only hdmi and/or dvi ?

Thanks in advance, and sorry for the bad english.

Answer (score 0):

See below for specific requirements, sourced from the [NVIDIA GEFORCE Surround Configuration Tool](http://www.geforce.co.uk/hardware/technology/surround/system-requirements)

**GeForce GTX 1070 Single-GPU With 2D Surround (Landscape)**

> Orientation: Landscape
>
> Accessory Display: Yes, no additional GPU (if using     3 or less displays)
>
> Maximum Resolution: 11520x2160
>
> Maximum Resolution (Bezel Correction):    10240x1600
>
> Maximum number of displays: 2-4 in Surround,1     Accessory Display when using 3 or less displays in     Surround

Special Instructions:

***Any connectors can be used to enable Surround.***

> Once Surround is enabled, users can use any 
>       connector for the Accessory Display.
>
> Max of 4 displays can be used simultaneously (3 if     monitors are 4K)
>
> G-SYNC and regular monitors can be mixed in     Surround; effects of G-SYNC will only be seen on     G-SYNC- enabled monitors

**GeForce GTX 1070 Single-GPU With 3D Surround (Landscape)**

> Orientation: Landscape
>
> Accessory Display: Yes, no additional GPU (if using    3 or less displays)
>
> Maximum Resolution: 11520x2160
>
> Maximum Resolution (Bezel Correction):    10240x1600
>
> Maximum number of displays: 2-4 in Surround,1    Accessory Display when using 3 or less displays in    Surround

Special Instructions:

> Once Surround is enabled, users can use any 
>       connector for the Accessory Display.
>
> Max of 4 displays can be used simultaneously (3 if    monitors are 4K)

***3D Vision Surround requires using three DVI or    three DisplayPort connectors***

***All monitors must be the same make and model for    3D Vision Surround***

> Using DisplayPort connectors may require the use    of DisplayPort to Dual-link DVI adapters. Please    consult your monitor's manual for supported 3D    connectors